# Shiny checkboxGroupInput with Choices Generated From ggplot

Tags: html, r, checkbox, shiny

I'm trying to create a checkbox for which the choices are plots created through ggplot. In the result, the UI looks like the HTML code itself instead of evaluating the HTML code to show the chart. Any ideas how I can get the checkboxGroupInput to show ggplots?

Sample code below -

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Plot check box"),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("plotscheckboxes")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {


    output$plot1 = renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars)+geom_point(aes(x=mpg,y=mpg))
    })

    output$plot2 = renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars)+geom_point(aes(x=mpg,y=mpg))
    })

    output$plotscheckboxes = renderUI({

      plotlist = list(
        plotOutput('plot1'),
        plotOutput('plot2')
      )


      plotlist2 = do.call(tagList, plotlist)

      # this just produces a list with 1,2, some sort of underlying value for the checkboxGroup     
      finaloptionlist = lapply(
        seq(length(plotlist2)),
        function(x) x
      )
      # the names of the list are what get used in the options so setting the names accordingly as the HTML code of the ggplot rendering
      names(finaloptionlist) = sapply(plotlist2, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "\n"))


checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
                         choices = finaloptionlist,
                         selected = 1)


    })

  }

))
```

Comment: Are you trying to read how many "plots" you pass to `output` and pass that to `checkboxGroupInput`?

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question correctly but in case I did - I don't need to pass all the output plots to the `checkboxGroupInput` choices. For simplicity, let's assume it's a set of n plots and I know the tags for each of these n plots such that I can generate `plotlist` in the above code.

Comment: Basically you wish to plot whatever plot is selected in the checkbox? What's the text you want next to the checkbox?

Comment: There is no text, the plot is the "text" of the checkbox itself. Think of some sort of dating website for example - four faces next to four radio buttons and you can pick.

Comment: Alternatively, the four faces could be the radio buttons themselves too (with no text or some text, doesn't matter).

Comment: A-ha, I see. Interesting problem. Can't think of anything other than creating figures from plots and attaching that to checkboxes using `img()` tag.

Comment: I'm glad you found it interesting :). I have another observation in case it helps - if you inspect the checkbox text element in the example on http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widget-gallery.html, it doesn't have the text "Choice 1", etc. in quotes whereas my code does. Can you think of any reason why there might this difference? If I can remove the quotes, I suspect it might work.

Comment: If you would like to discuss this, I recommend you visit the R-public chat room which offers better UI for chatting. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public